ApexCharts | Candlestick chart rendering issue on load in NextJS application
I have an issue where my candlestick chart (which is linked to a bar chart [intentionally]) does not render the candles on load. Can be seen below.

However, when I start to select on the volume bars a section it immediately displays. This tells me that the link between the two is responsible for re-rendering, just a guess.
I am using NextJS, as the title indicates and creating this using functional components.
Here is the component
'use client';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import { optionsBar, optionsCandlestick } from './options/options';
import { Box, Flex, Select, Text } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { BsChevronDown } from 'react-icons/bs';

const ApexChart = dynamic(() => import('react-apexcharts'), { ssr: false });

interface CandlestickData {
  name: string;
  data: { x: number; y: [number, number, number, number] }[];
}

interface VolumeData {
  name: string;
  data: { x: number; y: number }[];
}

const CandleStickChart: React.FC = () => {
  const [ohlcData, setOhlcData] = useState<CandlestickData[]>([]);
  const [volume, setVolume] = useState<VolumeData[]>([]);

  const generateRandomData = (count: number, minValue: number, maxValue: number): number[] => {
    const data: number[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      const randomValue = parseFloat((Math.random() * (maxValue - minValue) + minValue).toFixed(2));
      data.push(randomValue);
    }
    return data;
  };

  const generateCandlestickData = (
    count: number
  ): { x: number; y: [number, number, number, number] }[] => {
    const data: { x: number; y: [number, number, number, number] }[] = [];
    const startDate = new Date('2024-01-01').getTime();
    const interval = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      const timestamp = startDate + i * interval;
      const randomValues = generateRandomData(12, 1, 100);
      data.push({ x: timestamp, y: randomValues });
    }

    return data;
  };

  const generateBarChartData = (count: number): { x: number; y: number }[] => {
    const data: { x: number; y: number }[] = [];
    const startDate = new Date('2024-01-01').getTime();
    const interval = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      const timestamp = startDate + i * interval;
      const randomValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
      data.push({ x: timestamp, y: parseFloat(randomValue.toFixed(2)) });
    }

    return data;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const seriesCandlestick = [
      {
        name: 'series-1',
        data: generateCandlestickData(30),
      },
    ];

    const seriesBar = [
      {
        name: 'volume',
        data: generateBarChartData(30),
      },
    ];
    setOhlcData(seriesCandlestick);
    setVolume(seriesBar);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Box bg='tertiaryBackground' w={'xl'} p={4}>
      <Box id='chart-candlestick'>
        <ApexChart
          options={optionsCandlestick}
          series={ohlcData}
          type='candlestick'
          height={200}
          width={500}
        />
      </Box>
      <Box id='chart-bar'>
        <ApexChart options={optionsBar} series={volume} type='bar' height={100} width={500} />
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default CandleStickChart;

And here are the options
import { ApexOptions } from 'apexcharts';

export const optionsBar: ApexOptions = {
  chart: {
    height: 160,
    type: 'bar',
    brush: {
      enabled: true,
      target: 'candles',
    },
    selection: {
      enabled: true,
      xaxis: {
        min: new Date('20 Jan 2017').getTime(),
        max: new Date('10 Dec 2017').getTime(),
      },
      fill: {
        color: '#ccc',
        opacity: 0.4,
      },
      stroke: {
        color: '#0D47A1',
      },
    },
  },
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      columnWidth: '80%',
      barHeight: '40%',
      colors: {
        ranges: [
          {
            from: 0,
            to: 50,
            color: '#FF5C5C',
          },
          {
            from: 51,
            to: 100,
            color: '#34D1A6',
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  stroke: {
    width: 0,
  },
  xaxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    axisBorder: {
      offsetX: 13,
    },
  },
  yaxis: {
    labels: {
      show: true,
      style: {
        colors: '#9b9eab', // Color for x-axis labels
      },
    },
  },
};

export const optionsCandlestick: ApexOptions = {
  chart: {
    type: 'candlestick',
    height: 290,
    width: 500,
    id: 'candles',
    toolbar: {
      autoSelected: 'pan',
      show: false,
    },
    zoom: {
      enabled: false,
    },
  },
  plotOptions: {
    candlestick: {
      colors: {
        upward: '#34D1A6',
        downward: '#FF5C5C',
      },
    },
  },
  xaxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    axisTicks: {
      show: false,
    },
    labels: {
      show: false,
    },
    axisBorder: {
      show: false,
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false,
    },
  },
  grid: {
    borderColor: '#303030',
  },
  yaxis: {
    decimalsInFloat: 0,
    labels: {
      style: {
        colors: '#9b9eab',
      },
    },
  },
  tooltip: {
    enabled: true,
    shared: true,
    followCursor: true,
    intersect: false,
    inverseOrder: false,
    theme: 'dark',
    style: {
      fontSize: '14px',
      fontFamily: 'inherit',
    },
    x: {
      show: true,
      format: 'dd MMM yyyy',
    },
    marker: {
      show: true,
    },
    fixed: {
      enabled: false,
    },
  },
};

Of course I haven't used ApexCharts before now and would like to continue using it but if an alternative with good documentation could be provided instead then that could work too. All of ApexCharts' documentation demonstrates class-based components and with those I can see a render method of sorts but you need to create an instance of the class and there I lose the plot (pun intended) with an error.
Example from the documentation
var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);

chart.render();
// https://apexcharts.com/docs/creating-first-javascript-chart/

Similar to (if not the same) error in question
This expression is not constructable. Not all constituents of type 'ComponentType<Props>' are constructable. Type 'FunctionComponent<Props>' has no construct signatures.ts(2351) 
I have tried multiple permutations of the chart options, using the ApexCharts documentation as best I could.
